# Android: handle fling over recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using recyclerview, and I would like to handle the fling gesture. When I fling the vertical list after the animation the list stops in a position but this position is not an exact list position it can be between to list items.
After the animation in the onScrollStateChanged listener I can use the smoothScrollTo method to finish the moving when the state is SCROLL_STATE_IDLE , but in this case the animation stops and then restarts.
The question is that, can I get the amount of pixels of the fling before the fling starts and set it?

Comment: If you would like to make rows "clip" to the top (without being half/shown), you could look at RecyclerView.LayoutManager. I saw somewhere an example where people do the trick but I do not remember where it was exactly, unfortunately.

Comment: do you need `android.support.v7.widget.LinearSnapHelper`? (or in general `SnapHelper`?)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I need that helper, it works.

Comment: you are welcome...